# GIT strategy in handling 30+ repositories

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree, git-subtree

I'm thinking of a GIT strategy in handling  different build based on a master build. In need your opinion on how to effectively manage this large scale repo / super repo.

Basically I need a single repo that has a 30+ "sub" repos  in it. The reason why I need to have this kind of setup is because sooner or later  each build will have their own features  that shouldn't affect other builds.

What i have in mind is to create a separate branch for each build. With this approach, it will require me to create a separate build folder with the "master build" source code in it.

The problem with this is how do I apply a new feature across the builds without redoing it? Is there anyway to do this? Does anyone knows an effective way of handling this?   Thanks in advance!

```
Master Base Code -+-- build 1
                  |-- build 2
                  |-- build 3
                  |-- build n..
```

### Scenario 1: Build features

**Build 1**

- Header section is carousel.
- Body  have 2 columns

**Build 2**

- Header section is an image.
- Body have 1 column

**Build 2**

- Header section is a slider.
- Body have 1 column

*-- after finishing the features, the client wants to implement Build 1 carousel in other builds ---*

### Scenario 2: Apply build 1 carousel across the the different builds

**Build 1**

- Header section is carousel.
- Body  have 2 columns

**Build 2**

- Header section is carousel.
- Body have 1 column

**Build 2**

- Header section is carousel.
- Body have 1 column

This will become complicated in merging the "carousel" feature to other build because they have different base code.

Comment: Have you considered using just one code base, and making the features configurable? Having so many different builds seems unmanageable, not just because of git problems.

Comment: ummm yeah that was my plan before, knowing how the client thinks its impossible to use different env/config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`git submodules`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this.

Basically, within the base app, import each of repo1, repo2 ,.. rep30 as submodules.

Now, you can check out an updated tag on a specific submodule, while keeping all the other submodules versions same, and effectively create a corresponding build for the codebase.

Comment: Thanks will try this approach.  been reading about this for a while.